# jQuery Animated Progress Bar Issue

Tags: jquery, progress-bar

I am having a small jQuery issue, basically I am trying to build a progress bar that would load from 0 to the given percentage over a period of 1-2 seconds.

Look at what I have come so far based on a tutorial: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mWdgz/1/)

The fiddle wouldn't animate it, but let me describe what actually happens (apparently it does work on my test files).

So the progress bar does load as supposed but it stops at the value given to "title=" in html. It wouldn't accept percentages so if the set width is 460, to make the bar stop at 50%, I would have to give it a value of 230.

Another issue about this script is that only the first bar actually takes the real value, all other ones just "copy" the first one no matter the values given to them. Looks strange to me.

I am either looking for a way of solving both of these issues, or a better way of achieving the desired effect, preferrably with a way of inputting in percentages not pixel value.

Thanks.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Why not just use the jQuery.progressbar widget?

Comment: You forgot to add jQuery in your fiddle, works fine -> http://jsfiddle.net/mWdgz/5/

Comment: @adeneo doesn't work fine, all progressbar take same value if you use different title value for each one (not like in OP jsfiddle)

Comment: @roasted - But other than that, it works fine! Didn't see the issue as all titles are set to the same?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/mWdgz/4/

```
$("document").ready(function () {

    // animate the progress bar onload

    $('.progress_bar').each(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            width: this.title
        }, 1000);
    })

});
```